# Cut specific part of path

Tags: string, inno-setup, pascalscript

Here is the code from Inno Setup

```
function GetDirName(const Value: string): string;
    var 
    InstallPath: string;
    begin

    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IconExtractor\DefaultIcon', '', InstallPath)

    Result := InstallPath;
    end;
```

The result is as below:

> Result = C:\ProgramFiles\Solutions\Extractor\tools\v3\iconextractor.exe,1

But i only want to remove the last 3 path elements

> C:\Program Files\Solutions\Extractor

How i can do it?

Comment: What does it mean "I only want this"? Can you be more specific? Do you want to remove the last 3 path components?

Comment: Exactly. That's it

Comment: So edit your question to say so.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Thanks for the info, now it just removing 1 path (iconextractor.exe,1). How i can remove the remaining 2 paths?

Comment: Just call it three times!

Comment: Im calling it three times but i get the same result

Comment: Use `ExtractFileDir` instead

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : You are right Just tested : doing 3 times `InstallPath := ExtractFileDir(InstallPath);` does the same job. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try little bit of code

```
function GetDirName(const Value: string): string;
var 
 InstallPath : string;
 I,bscount   : Integer;

begin
 RegQueryStringValue(HKLM,'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\IconExtractor\DefaultIcon',
                        '', InstallPath);
 bscount := 0;

 for I := Length(InstallPath) downto 1 do begin
   if InstallPath[I] = '\' then Inc(bscount);
   if bscount = 3 then begin
      InstallPath := Copy(InstallPath,1,I-1);
      break;
   end;
end;// for

Result := InstallPath;
end;
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly! Finally i got it thanks to you :)

Comment: @user3796104 : you are welcome :)